# How to make X-axis more clear if it's values are a bit lengthy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have a string array which consists of minutes and seconds like 10:03, 10:13,..... at an interval of ten seconds. There are 360 values in this array and I want to plot it on x-axis but the graph looks like this:
[Time array on X-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTERV.png)

It is showing all the points on X-axis which is why there is a huge black bar. How do I make the X-axis more clear so that it only shows a few points on the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code may be helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(range(0,100,10),["number"+str(i) for i in x], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```